# Fouriers Transform inconsistency with intuition

Tags: fourier-transform

lets consider Fourier Transform of function 
$
 f(t) =
\begin{cases}
e^{-t},  & \text{for $t\ge 0$ } \\
-e^t, & \text{for $t\lt0$ }
\end{cases}$ 
with Fourier Transform $F\{\omega\}= \frac{-1}{i\omega-1}+\frac{1}{i\omega+1}$

Magnitude and phase plots below:

[Mag and phase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ID3DK.png)

With all phases equal to zero this means that signal can be recreated with infinite amount of  pure cosine waves each with diffrent frequency and amplitude but same property at t=0, which is positive value at that point.  There is like infinite number of cosine waves only beetween   $\omega=0$ and $\omega=0,00000001$, so how is that possible all of these sum to 1 at t=0?

Answer (score 1):

They'd need to be sine waves, not cosines, as the function $f$ is odd. The function is discontinuous at the origin, with 'average value' zero ($+1$ to the right, $-1$ to the left), which is what the Fourier series would give you at $t=0$. When $f$ is discontinuous, agreement of the function and its Fourier series becomes difficult (I realise that's a vague statement but I suspect you're not after a fancy justification).

Answer (score 0):

I am so sorry, Ive made such a trivial error in equation. It should be $$  f(t) =
\begin{cases}
e^{-t},  & \text{for $t \ge 0$} \\
e^t, & \text{for $t\lt$ 0}
\end{cases}$$

With chart like below
[Function plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bhzsd.png)

Why did you refer to Fourier Series as function isnt periodic?